# Next JS Error occurred prerendering page 404 in Next: 14.0.4 with next js pages structure (old page structure)

Tags: next.js14

I hope this message finds you well. I'm currently facing an issue with prerendering in Next.js version 14. The error specifically occurs when attempting to prerender the "/404" page. The project utilizes an older pages structure in Next.js.

Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error:  should not be imported outside of pages/_document.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-import-in-page

I want to run this 404 page with latest version Next.js 14